# User identification problem when I try to launch DB2-kk

Tags: db2

I click the button "Go to UI" and appears the following message:
{"trace":"46b4bb4886e31314ef92057b01d07ffb","errors":[{"code":"iam_sqlid_error","message":"HWCSEC6011E: User id can not be found for current instance.","target":{"type":"","name":""},"more_info":""}]}

Comment: What Db2 version, platform, OS? From the error it looks like you might be using Db2 on Cloud on IBM Cloud...? If yes, is it a Lite plan?

Comment: Thank you for your time, I use IBM Cloud, it is a Lite plan

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error for my Db2 lite plan. My solution was to delete the current Db2 service and create a new one (since you are only allowed to have one lite plan at a time). Worth mentioning is that if you have important data in your Db2 instance, maybe consider copying the data first. I did not have anything of importance so it was easy to just create a new lite plan.

Comment: Thank you. The problem just fixed. I didn't do anything.